# VS2012 not running any tests

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mstest

When trying to run tests in any way from VS2012, either nothing happens or this error appears in the output log:

`An exception occurred while test discoverer 'MSTestDiscoverer' was loading tests. Exception: Root element is missing.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Root element is missing` means there's an XML file somewhere with no root element. In my case, my unit test project had a testsettings file with nothing in it. The fix was to simply delete the testsettings file